# MS-Access SQL DISTINCT GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, distinct

I am currently trying to `SELECT` the `DISTINCT FirstNames` in a `GROUP`, using Microsoft Access 2010.
The simplified relevant columns of my table looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| ID | GroupNumber | FirstName |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |           1 | Peter     |
|  2 |           1 | Bob       |
|  3 |           1 | Peter     |
|  4 |           2 | Rosemary  |
|  5 |           2 | Jamie     |
|  6 |           3 | Peter     |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

My actual table contains two columns to which I want to apply this process (separately), but I should be able to simply repeat the process for the other column. The column group number is a simplification, my table actually groups all rows in a ten day interval together, but I've already solved that problem.

And I would like it to return this:

```
+-------------+------------+
| GroupNumber | FirstNames |
+-------------+------------+
|           1 | Peter      |
|           1 | Bob        |
|           2 | Rosemary   |
|           2 | Jamie      |
|           3 | Peter      |
+-------------+------------+
```

This means that I want all Distinct FirstNames for each Group.
A regular `DISTINCT` would ignore group boundaries and only mention Peter once. All aggregate functions reduce my output to only one value or don't work on strings at all. Access also doesn't support `SELECT`ing columns that are not aggregates or in the `GROUP BY` statement.

All other answers I've found either want an aggregate, are not applicable to MS Access or are solved by working around the data in ways not applicable to my case. *(Standardized languages are a nice thing, aren't they?)*

My current (invalid) query looks like this:

```
SELECT GroupNumber,
    DISTINCT FirstNames -- This is illegal, distinct applies to all
                        -- columns and doesn't respect groups.
FROM Example AS b
-- Complicated stuff to make the groups
GROUP BY GroupNumber;
```

This query is a one time thing and is used to analyze a 58000 row *excel spreadsheet exported from another Database* (not my fault), so optimizing for runtime is not necessary.

I would like to achieve this purely through SQL and without VBA if at all possible.

Comment: Just use `SELECT DISTINCT GroupNumber, FirstNames`

Comment: But that would return groupNumber: 1,2,3 and FirstNames: Peter,Bob,Rosemary,Jamie,Peter

Comment: No, it won't. Did you try it?

Comment: And also DISTINCT is forbidden with group by.

Comment: That's why I didn't use `GROUP BY`, use only `DISTINCT`

Comment: Yeah, but now it only returns every name in the entire table once, not once per group.

Comment: That's just not true. You aren't using the query I posted

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I had to adjust it to the way my groups work and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GroupNumber, FirstNames
FROM Example AS b
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this problem would be group by the columns GroupNumber and FirstNames at the same time. The query is presented below:

```
Select GroupNumber,  FirstNames
From input
Group By GroupNumber, FirstNames
```

(Standardized languages are a nice thing, aren't they?)